# How to get Background from another Activity?

Tags: java, android, colors, background

I want to change the background-color of another Activity (start) in my Settings-Activity (choose between different colors, sounds etc.).

How can I change the color of another Activity?

I tried to get the Background from my start-Activity (id:start) with:

> ```
>     final RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.start);
> ```

but it seems it doesn´t work.

Full Code of the Settings-Activity:

```
public class activity_settings extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_settings);
    ColorChange();
}

public void ColorChange() {
    final RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.start);

    final RadioButton ChangeToBlue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button_blue);
    final RadioButton ChangeToRed = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button_red);


    final Button button_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    button_save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ChangeOption(background);
        }
    });


    ChangeToBlue.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            ChangeToBlue(background);
        }
    });

    ChangeToRed.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            ChangeToRed(background);
        }

    });


}



public void ChangeOption(RelativeLayout background) {
    if (background.isEnabled()) {
        background.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        background.setEnabled(true);

    }
}

public void ChangeToBlue(RelativeLayout background) {
    background.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    background.invalidate();

}
public void ChangeToRed(RelativeLayout background) {
    background.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    background.invalidate();

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Comment: I can't quite get you, so you want to change background color of new activity which you will call by startActivity() ?

Comment: Make use of broadcast receiver, register in onCREATE of your first activity with some intent filter. 
No when when you navigate to Settings Activity and your first activity is in background but not yet destroyed u can still listen for the broadcasts sent from Setting Activtiy to change background.

Answer (score 1):

Save color code i.e. #F0F0F0 from your setting-activity in a sharedPreference and get this value in onCreate() of activity in which you want to set background.